# Prepare bootable Mac OS install usb on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, dmg-image

Is there any software out there that can simulate Disk Utility (Mac app) for Windows?

I need to reinstall leopard on my Mac because I screwed something up on the current OS. The thing is, the DVD drive is broken on there, so I need to prepare a bootable USB drive from my Leopard DMG file.

This is easily done with the Disk Utility app on the Mac. But seeing how my cannot even log on to my Mac right now, I don't know how to prepare that USB stick. The only other machine I have is a PC with Windows 7.

If anyone has any suggestion, please help me out!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) to copy the files from the installer DVD to the flash drive, and then boot off that flash drive on your Mac. You might have to format the flash drive as HFS (although I cannot seem to remember if MacDrive lets you format drives)

Once you have fixed your install, I suggest you follow the guide I wrote for [][2] to create a bootable repair partition on your Mac, so you will always be able to boot into the OS X installer, regardless of if you have the DVD or not

[2]:

Comment: Yup MAcDrive was a big help! MacDrive 8 does support HFS+